# Поиск в ширину, сохранение пути в графе

Tags: c#, графы

Здравствуйте.

Проблема такая: есть матрица смежности, обозначающая мой граф. Есть функция поиска в ширину. Я указываю в ней целевую вершину (в данном коде 5), и в текст бокс он выводит весь путь, что он прошел до целевой вершины (например, 1 - 2 - 11- 3 - 4 - 5), а мне нужен кратчайший путь (1--2--5) (из начального состояния в целевой), я понимаю.

Вот мой граф:

```
private void draw()
        {                         // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
            a = new float[n, n] {   {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },  //1
                                    {1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//2
                                    {1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//3
                                    {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//4
                                    {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//5
                                    {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//6
                                    {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0 },//7
                                    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0 },//8
                                    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//9
                                    {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0 },//10
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0 },//11
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0 },//12
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//13
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 },//14
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//15
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//16
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//17
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 },//18
                                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0 }//19
                                };


        }
```

А вот функция поиска:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            draw();
            temp = "";
            rebra = new int[n, n];
            //Очередь вершин на рассмотрение
            Queue<int> openVertex = new Queue<int>();
            Queue<int> Way = new Queue<int>();
            //Список уже рассмотренных вершин
            List<int> CloseVertex = new List<int>();
            //Начинаем обход с 1й вершины
            openVertex.Enqueue(0);
            //До тех пор, пока не обошли все вершины
            while (openVertex.Count != 0)
            {
                //Выталкиваем из начала списка индекс текущей вершины
                int index = openVertex.Dequeue();
                if (index == 5) break;
              //  textBox2.Text += Convert.ToString(index);
                for (short j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    //Если ребро не нулевое 
                    if (a[index, j] != 0)
                    {
                        //И вершина еще не была рассмотрена и не находится в очереди на рассмотрение
                        if (!CloseVertex.Contains(j) && !openVertex.Contains(j))
                        {
                            //Добавить вершину в список на рассмотрение
                            openVertex.Enqueue(j);
                            rebra[index, j] = 1;


                        }
                    }
                    else rebra[index, j] = 0;

                }
                //Добавляем информацию о вершине в строку вывода
                temp += " -> " + Convert.ToString(index + 1);
                //Добавляем вершину в список уже рассмотренных
                CloseVertex.Add(index);
            }
            textBox1.Text += q + "Прохождение графа А в ширину:";
            textBox1.Text += q + temp;
        }
```

Граф визуально (представил в виде дерева для удобства и понимания):

[image]

Comment: @Northex, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Алгоритм по идее правильный (я не заглядывал в детали имплементации), но вы неправильно интерпретируете результат.

По сути алгоритм одновременно пытается идти по нескольким путям, и тот путь, который первым приводит к цели, и есть нужный (причём кратчайший). А ваш код с `temp` запоминает вершины из всех путей вместе. Это не то, что вам надо.

Смотрите. Легче всего для каждой вершины, в которую вы попадаете, запоминать вершину, *откуда* вы в неё попали, в отдельном массиве (назовите его «массив предшественников»: `predecessor`. Тогда чтобы после окончания обхода найти сам путь, вам надо просто от целевой вершины пройтись по предшественникам до начала. Всё!